# and/or conditions in a SQL query

Tags: sql, logic

I have to select all the records where FIELD1 is value11 or value12 and FIELD2 is value21, value22, value23, ... or value29. All 2*9=18 pairs of admissible values for FIELD1 and FIELD2 are possible.
Which is the most compact form to write down my SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where field1 in (value11, value12)
and field2 in (value21, value22, value23, ..., value29)
```

(Where you need to replace the dots with all `value24` and so on.)

Comment: @Arjan: `BETWEEN` is another option. `[...] WHERE [...] FIELD2 BETWEEN VALUE21 AND VALUE29`

Comment: @Sathya, that would be true if the values are really subsequent. (I understood they are database columns themselves?)

Comment: (That's too soon of an accepted answer for trying to find the most compact form!)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have updated my question since I have recognized that my situation is a bit more complex. So, please see http://superuser.com/questions/199517/and-or-like-conditions-in-a-sql-query

Comment: @Arjan Indeed, that's why I mentioned as a supplementary comment.